# TCP frequent drop packet

Tags: networking, tcp, kernel

I use Centos 8.1, kernel version 4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64. These days we get frequent TCP packet dropped. When I use dropwatch I get this info:

```
dropwatch> start
Enabling monitoring...
Kernel monitoring activated.
Issue Ctrl-C to stop monitoring
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
1 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
6 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
1 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
3 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
1 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
1 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
3 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
1 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
2 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
1 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
3 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
1 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
1 drops at sk_stream_kill_queues+48 (0xffffffff9e6e34b8)
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
2 drops at tcp_v4_rcv+48 (0xffffffff9e7892f8)
4 drops at tcp_v4_do_rcv+6b (0xffffffff9e7882ab)
2 drops at unix_stream_connect+4fa (0xffffffff9e7dd9aa)
```

As my sysctl.conf setting is :

```
vm.swappiness = 0
kernel.sysrq = 1

net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 120

# see details in https://help.aliyun.com/knowledge_detail/39428.html
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 2
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_announce = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2

# see details in https://help.aliyun.com/knowledge_detail/41334.html
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 5000
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2



#open bbr
net.core.default_qdisc=fq
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=bbr
net.ipv4.tcp_notsent_lowat = 16384



net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency=1

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 33554432 33554432 33554432
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 33554432 33554432 33554432
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432


net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 4096
net.core.dev_weight = 64

net.core.optmem_max = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0
```